# Filter from current to the end in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I filter my results from the current element to the end in JQuery?

There are some filters:

- Opened;
- Closed;
- SomethingElse;
- Finished;

For example, I need that these rows will be showed from 'Closed' to 'Finished', including all between them by the filters order, the rows in random order:

```
<tr class='row' data-row-choice="Opened">
<tr class='row' data-row-choice="Closed">
<tr class='row' data-row-choice="SomethingElse">
<tr class='row' data-row-choice="Opened">
<tr class='row' data-row-choice="Finished">
```

I can't understand a logic of this action.

EDIT: Added some explanations to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) and attribute equals selector along with `.addSelf()` and `.add()` for adding start and end element as well:

```
$('[data-row-choice="Closed"]')
  .nextUntil('[data-row-choice="Finished"]')//gets all inbetween element
     .andSelf()//add start element
       .add('[data-row-choice="Finished"]')//add end element
         .show();
```

### Working Demo

Comment: If all these rows are showed and then I want to show rows from 'Closed' to 'Finished', I must use '$('.row').hide()' before your first row of answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)

```
$(".row[data-row-choice='Closed']").nextUntil(".row[data-row-choice='Finished']").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below fiddle example

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/n38emL5m/`
```